# grabbing URL session tokens using php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to interact with an search form with php curl, I am missing 2 url parameters that appear to be assigned to me when the submit form is searched, the problem is since I am using CURL GET requests, I can't build the proper url without the 2 tokens, (seem to be time sensitive) here is what I have so far to build the url

```
$url="http://mysite/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?Search_Arg=$argumentvariable&PID=q3a1yMo8IHMJV0b9VnWf2lbLc1SIJ(some random token here)&SEQ=20130506222916(appears to be time format)";
$headers = array(
    'Host: mysite',

);
$ch = curl_init();                   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://somesite.org');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I can probably caculate the SEQ but I am stuck on how to get the PID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php):

```
$url="http://mysite/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?Search_Arg=$argumentvariable&PID=q3a1yMo8IHMJV0b9VnWf2lbLc1SIJ(some random token here)&SEQ=20130506222916(appears to be time format)";

$parsed = parse_url( $url );
parse_str( $parsed['query'], $data );

echo $data['pid'];
```